# Why doesnt my scanf work in the function?

Tags: c

When I take the rows and cols from scanf-s into the main function they work.
but in this function they dont work, they dont get used in the for loops.
whats the problem?

```
void function (int rows, int cols, int array[S][S])
{   
 int i, j;
 scanf ("%d", &rows);
 scanf ("%d", &cols);

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            while (array[i][j]<1 || array[i][j]>S)
            scanf ("%d", &array[i][j]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Separate the reading of rows cols from this function, then change the function to this: `void function (int rows, int cols, int array[rows][cols])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are complaining that the changes to parameters `rows` and `cols` are not visible in the calling function.

This is because C is a pass-by-value language.

The change would be:

```
int main(void)
{
    int rows;
    int cols
    int array[5][5];

    caller( &rows, &cols, array);  // Pass by pointer, not value.

    /* Now, rows and cols have been properly set */

    return 0;
}

/* Parameters are received as references, not values */    
void function (int *p_rows, int* p_cols, int array[5][5])
{   
 int i, j;
 scanf ("%d", p_rows);
 scanf ("%d", p_cols);

    for (i = 0; i < *p_rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < *p_cols; j++)
        {
            while (array[i][j]<1 || array[i][j]>5)
                scanf ("%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. thanks this worked perfectly.
if you have time it would be lovely if you would eli5 why it worked exactly.
why does scanf-ing into the array work the regular way and why i needed to use the method you provided to get rows, cols working? 
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The condition of while loop may be wrong since the very beginning.  You don't know the initial value of `array[i][j]`